# Laravel не видит константу

Tags: php, laravel

Я использую Laravel 9.x. Я прописал в web.php следующее:

```
Route::get('/start/', function () {
return view('start', [
    'example' => '123'
]);
```

});

В шаблоне у меня:

```
<h1>Ответ: <i>{{ example }}</i></h1>
```

Но я получаю ошибку `Undefined constant "example"`. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Потому что тут `'/start/` ты не закрыл кавычку............ ругается он не на шаблон

Comment: Это опечатка при копировании кода

Comment: а я уверен что нет...........ведь ты копировал, а не заново руками перепечатывал посимвольно

Comment: Я проверил, кавычка на месте. Иначе бы syntax error был бы. Я копировал и чутка менял, ибо много лишнего для простого вопроса, например, контроллер.

Comment: и вот прям так и надо писать `{{ example }}`,  не `{{ $example }}` ?

Comment: не знаю, в интернетах так было ‍♂️

Comment: Посмотрел пару статей, там именно с долларом написано

Comment: да ладно, сработало!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views   ........ https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/views

Comment: Спасибо большое! Может, вы как ответ напишете, а я его отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли добавить символ $

```
{{ $example }}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало